# How to Detect When User Reaches Bottom of the Screen and Trigger a Function in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, geometryreader

What is the best way to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of the screen and trigger a specific function in SwiftUI?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Text("Pokedex")
                    .font(.custom("Pokemon Solid", size: 25))
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .opacity(0.3)
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns, spacing: 5) {
                            ForEach(viewModel.filteredPokemon) { pokemon in
                                NavigationLink(destination: PokemonDetailView(pokemon: pokemon)
                                ) {
                                    PokemonView(vm: viewModel, pokemon: pokemon)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: viewModel.filteredPokemon.count)
                        .navigationTitle("Pokedexarino")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                        if geometry.frame(in: .global).maxY == geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom {
                            Text("Reached the bottom")
                            //TODO: make load 30 at a time
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchText)
            }
        }
    }
    .environmentObject(viewModel)
}
```

I tried to create a function but I think there may be a built in function that can do this. I tried Geometry reader.

Comment: There is no built in function for this.

Comment: You might want to look into ScrollReader

Answer (score 0):

You can add paging to your `ScrollView` by displaying an additional row at the bottom if more data is available, then using the `.task` modifier to load the next page, e.g.

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumns, spacing: 5) {
        ForEach(viewModel.filteredPokemon) { pokemon in
            NavigationLink(destination: PokemonDetailView(pokemon: pokemon)
            ) {
                PokemonView(vm: viewModel, pokemon: pokemon)
            }
        }
        if viewModel.moreDataAvailable {
            Text("Reached the bottom")
                .task {
                    await viewModel.loadNextPage()
                }
        }
    }
}
```